# How do I create a circuit based on this truth table? The solution I implemented is not working as expected

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, circuits

I am trying to create a circuit based on this truth table below:
can you describe how to make the circuit using only logic gates

```
In_1 In_2 In_3  Out
 0    0    0     0
 0    0    1     1
 0    1    0     1
 0    1    1     1
 1    0    0     1
 1    0    1     1
 1    1    0     1
 1    1    1     1
```

This is what I have done so far
[image: my work]

However, this circuit is not working as expected. It is giving me this error:
[image: error]

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and how do I fix this? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: A single OR-gate can handle this, which makes it far too trivial a question. That makes one wonder why the OP provided such a complex solution. As @ttnick suggests, it seems most likely that there is a mistake in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this software but as you have a fan-in of at least three, a simple OR gate should suffice as your function is 1 if at least one input is set to 1.

The input $(1, 0, 0)$ is evaluated to $0$ as your AND gate will return $0$ and use this result together with the $0$s from $x_2, x_3$ in the OR gate but I don't see what is wrong with the input $(1, 1, 1)$. It might be that the expected output is wrongly specified there?